# Base64 image decode in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, base64

I have function for image upload:

```
public function upload(UploadImageRequest $request)
{
    $storagePath=Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();

    $image = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images', time().'_'.$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName());

    $url = Storage::url($image);
    $image = Image::make([]);

    $image->path = $storagePath.$url;
    $image->url = "$url";
    $image->saveOrFail();

    return Response::json($image, ResponseHttp::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

It's work fine, but I want to add fucntionality if frontend send me picture in base64. How it decode?

Answer (score 1):

To decode base64 image use this -

```
$decode = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $image));
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: And how save file after it?

Comment: For example,  $info = @getimagesizefromstring($decode);
                       $mime_type = $info['mime'];
                       $extn = image_type_to_extension($info[2]);
                       $filename = md5(time() . uniqid()) . $extn;
                       file_put_contents($folder_path . '/' . $filename, $decode);

Comment: file_put_contents(public/images/4da589d76150606ceac7d29b9321a6a6): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: directory exist

Comment: Please give full path till public and then your filename.extention . cause file_put_contents() function puts $decode i.e image data to destination i.e var/www/html/project_folder/public/filename.extention. So it should be like this - file_put_contents(var/www/html/project_folder/public/filename.extention,$decode);